# Error Installing binding_of_caller-0.6.8 Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Getting this error when trying to install binding_of_caller, but only for this specific version. I've tried lots of searching but can't figure it out.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/bluefantail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binding_of_caller.c
binding_of_caller.c:4:10: fatal error: 'vm_core.h' file not found
#include "vm_core.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binding_of_caller.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bluefantail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/binding_of_caller-0.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/bluefantail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/binding_of_caller-0.6.8/ext/binding_of_caller/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

> You need to update to v0.7.1 to get Ruby 2.0.0 support.

https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/issues/16#issuecomment-14028817

This comment would be a solution.